# Round off digits in character format

Tags: r

I have a character variable which has some values in fraction. I want them to be shown in %.

```
x <- data.frame(categoreis = c('[0.00954,0.01679)','[0.10023,0.30980]', 'Total','[-200,100]'))
```

Desired output in data.frame format-

```
'[0.954%,1.679%)','[10.023%,30.980%]', 'Total','[-200,100]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use functions from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
#Find out values which has fraction values. 
inds <- str_detect(x$categoreis, "\\d+\\.\\d+")
#Extract the numbers from the string, multiply it with 100 and add % sign
x$categoreis[inds] <- str_replace_all(x$categoreis[inds], "\\d+\\.\\d+", 
                       function(m) str_c(as.numeric(m) * 100, "%"))

x
#        categoreis
#1  [0.954%,1.679%)
#2 [10.023%,30.98%]
#3            Total
#4         -200,100
```

**data**

Make sure to read data as characters and not factors with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
x <- data.frame(categoreis = c('[0.00954,0.01679)','[0.10023,0.30980]', 
                'Total','[-200,100]'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Well appreciated. I just realised [-200,100] also in brackets

Comment: @john In that case use `inds <- str_detect(x$categoreis, "\\d+\\.\\d+")`

Comment: Is it possible to round off [0.954%,1.679%) and convert to [1.0%,1.7%)

Comment: @john yes, change the function inside to `str_c(round(as.numeric(m) * 100, 1), "%"))`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it returns [95.4%%,167.9%%)

Comment: yes, because you have changed it (multiplied by 100) once already and now you are changing (multiplying by 100) it again. Try it on fresh `x`.

Comment: Got it. I run the same thing twice. Thank you so much!

Comment: Last question - Is there any way to run this only on fractions (<1)? Currently it converts 100.21 to % as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: Got it with (inds <- str_detect(x$categoreis, "\\[0\\.\\d+"))